# ¿Es incorrecto usar "los" en lugar de "os" o "les"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, gramática, pronombres

En la pregunta [¿Qué significa "os"?](https://es.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080906073116AAP7mD9) se dan un par de ejemplos en que en lugar de "os" se puede usar "les", pero nunca se habla de "los", que es como habitualmente usamos en donde vivo.

¿Es incorrecto usar *los* en lugar de *les* o de *os*?

Ejemplo:

- Nosotros *os* miramos
- Nosotros *les* miramos
- Nosotros *los* miramos

Comment: Depende de muchos factores. En principio ninguno es estrictamente incorrecto ya que hay dialectos que permiten las tres formas para objetos directos (además, verbos de percepción han variado a lo largo del tiempo si tienden a complementos directos o indirectos), pero puede que lo sea en algún dialecto en concreto. Para que podamos ayudarte más, ¿cuál es el tuyo?

Comment: español rioplatense supongo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Respuesta corta: no, no es incorrecto. El uso del pronombre *lo* (o *los*) para el complemento directo masculino nunca es incorrecto, aunque en algunos casos se pueda aceptar el uso de *le* (o *les*).

Lo que nos encontramos en este caso es el llamado *dativo de cortesía*, que es una forma habitual de leísmo. Es bastante frecuente que un hablante utilice las formas *le* o *les* para el objeto directo cuando se refieren a usted o ustedes; es decir, cuando funcionan como pronombres de segunda persona y no de tercera. En muchas zonas (España y también algunos lugares de América) esta práctica está tan extendida que casi nadie usa los pronombres acusativos (*lo*, *los*) para este caso, por lo que un hablante de estas zonas tenderá a obviarlos o incluso los considerará incorrectos. Pero no lo son.

Naturalmente, también hay muchos hablantes que usan *le* o *les* para un complemento directo de tercera persona, pero no es tan habitual como este caso y no creo que en este caso se pueda producir el error de rechazar los pronombres acusativos.

Comment: Pues aqui se usa los o les pero nunca "os". De hecho tuve que buscar una respuesta en internet para ver exactamente qué queria decir esta palabra

Answer (score 1):

Si nos ponemos estrictos, mirar va con un objeto directo:

> yo miro el televisor ---> yo lo miro
>
> yo miro la televisión ---> yo la miro

no con un objeto indirecto:

> *yo le miro

Aunque hay zonas donde este uso de le (llamado leísmo) está muy extendido.

los y os son ambos (entre otras cosas) pronombres de objeto directo (o "acusativos"), pero los corresponde a ellos, y os a vosotros.

Ustedes, va siempre con verbos y pronombres de tercera persona del plural (ellos/ellas), por lo tanto, lo correcto es:

> yo os miro a vosotros  (en España se considera informal, en Argentina no se usa)
>
> yo los miro a ustedes  (en España se considera formal, en Argentina es la única forma)
>
> yo las miro a ustedes  (si hablamos con un grupo exclusivamente de mujeres)

Puede haber zonas donde esto se mezcle por distintos motivos, pero esa sería la base.