# ¿En la oración nosotros les miramos, es "les" objeto directo u objeto indirecto y por qué?

Tags: objetos-indirectos, objetos-directos

De acuerdo a esta pregunta,

[Es incorrecto usar "los" en lugar de "os" o "les"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21546/es-incorrecto-usar-los-en-lugar-de-os-o-les)

Se puede decir tanto "Nosotros les miramos" como "Nosotros los miramos". De acuerdo a esto, supongo que si la función de los o les es la misma, ambos deben ser objeto directo u objeto indirecto. Si entiendo bien la persona que respondió dice que es objeto directo, pero no entiendo qué regla se usa para diferenciarlos.

Viendo las reglas para diferenciar objetos directos de objetos indirectos me encuentro con que aparentemente todas aplican a los 2 casos. Por ejemplo, una forma de identificarlo dice que si puedo reemplazar un fragmento de la oración por "los" es objeto directo y si lo puedo reemplazar por "les" es objeto indirecto. Pero aquí los puede ser reemplazado por les y cumplir la misma función en la oración así que supongo que esta ayuda no me dice nada.

[Objeto directo](https://www.ejemplos.co/objeto-directo/)

Otra regla dice que un objeto directo responde a la pregunta "a quién".  Pero la misma regla aparece en objeto indirecto.

[Objeto indirecto](https://www.ejemplos.co/objeto-indirecto/)

Si preguntando "a quién" puede ser tanto objeto indirecto como objeto indirecto, esta regla no me dice nada.

Otra regla de objeto indirecto dice que el objeto indirecto suele estar introducido con la preposición "a". Pero en la oración "Llamé a mi mamá", "mi mamá" es objeto directo y está introducido por la preposición "a", así que esta regla tampoco me asegura nada.

Y finalmente otra regla dice que el objeto directo recibe la acción del verbo directamente y siempre en primer lugar. Aquí la palabra está antes del verbo, así que no sé cómo esta regla se aplica, y aparte existen oraciones como "Le compré un obsequio a mi suegra" (le objeto indirecto) y "Los traje para que repasemos" (los objeto directo), ambos "le" y "los" antes del verbo y siendo un caso objeto directo y otro objeto indirecto. O al menos todo esto dicen los links que hice referencia.

En fin, mi pregunta es,

¿En la oración nosotros les miramos, es "les" objeto directo u objeto indirecto y porqué?

Comment: Todo objeto directo animado obliga la preposición *a*.  Por eso, es más fácil determinar estas cosas reemplazando una persona con, por ejemplo, una empresa que no admite *a personal*.  Si te suena bien *Llamé la empresa* es objeto directo, si te tendría que ser *llamé a la empresa*, pues es indirecto.

Comment: Otra «prueba» está en si podemos hacer de la persona/cosa en cuestión el sujeto de una oración pasiva.  Si te suena bien «mi mamá fue llamada (por mí)», pues la mamá es objeto directo.  Si no, pues no lo es (*di el regalo a mi amigo* puede ser *el regalo fue dado* pero no *mi amigo fue dado*, así que el regalo es directo y el amigo indirecto).

Comment: En *nosotros les miramos*, suponemos que es un objeto directo (*ellos/ellas/ustedes fueron vistos/as por nosotros*) en un dialecto mínimamente leísta (sea de cortesía o no).  Pero igual si ser objeto indirecto.  Lo que pasa es que en una oración aislada como *nosotros les miramos*, no hay suficiente información y falta contexto para determinar el caso de *les* con absoluta certeza.

Comment: O sea, aquí tendría que plantear una oración como "ellos fueron mirados por nosotros"  y así concluir que es un objeto directo ?

Comment: https://www.rae.es/dpd/mirar depende del sentido si es transitivo o intransitivo....No quiero reproducir todo eso aqui. Para una persona: mirar a alguien. indirecto. Yo estaba mirando a Carlos. [...] Le miraba las piernas»

Comment: @lambie pero eso es sólo para algunos verbos? No tengo muy claro lo que dice, si es una persona va "a" y sino no va? El verbo llamar por ejemplo, puedes decir llamé a Juan o llamé a un celular.

Comment: Hasta ahora la explicación que me pareció más entendible es la de tranformarlo en voz pasiva, si es que es correcta, todas las explicaciones que listé en mi pregunta parecen estar sólo para confundir.

Comment: Hay que ver el verbo y ver si admite los dos usos o no. Mirar puede ser las dos cosas como explica la RAE. La explicación en la RAE es completa pero muy larga para poner aqui.

Comment: @user0721090601 a que te refieres con animado? A que es un ser vivo? Y otra cosa, la regla del si suena bien puede servir para alguien que sabe Español, pero que hay de alguien que está aprendiendo el idioma? La única forma con esa regla sería conocer verbo por verbo o como se dice oración por oración para saber si es objeto directo u objeto indirecto?

Comment: La animacidad (animado o inanimado) es algo de gramática, tal como el número (singular o plural), género (masculino, femenino, neutro) o persona (primera, segunda, tercera).  Lo que pasa es que generalmente la animacidad no se refleja en castellano, pero más claramente se ve en la cuestión del objeto directo.  Los objetos directos animados obligan una *a personal*, y los no animados lo rechazan.

Comment: En español, son animadas todas las personas además de los animales (u otras cosas) a que les ascribimos cualidades humanas como perros.  La animacidad con los no humanos no se rige por alguna regla fija, sino refleja una perspectiva del hablante.  Para la mayoría, una vaca no admite la *a*, pero para un vaquero con vaca premiada que casi es miembro de familia es diferente.  Yo la he escuchado hasta con los coches para las personas que cuidan mucho (demasiado) de sus coches.

Answer (score 1):

"Nosotros **les** miramos" es un caso de leísmo. Lo correcto es usar "los":

- Nosotros **los** miramos.

El pronombre "los" es **objeto directo**, y por lo tanto en su forma nominativa ("ellos") puede ser sujeto de la voz pasiva:

- Ellos son mirados por nosotros.

En:

- Llamé a mi mamá.

"mi mamá" es el **objeto directo**, introducido por "a" por ser un objeto directo animado.

- **La** llamé.

En la oración que aparece en un comentario:

- Llamé a la empresa.

el verbo "llamar" es intransitivo, y "a la empresa" es un circunstancial de lugar.

Ver esta entrada de "llamar" en el diccionario:

> 2. tr. Realizar las operaciones necesarias para establecer comunicación telefónica con alguien. La llamé, pero no estaba en casa. **U. t. c. intr. Llama a su oficina.**